# AWS Lambda can't access VPC resources

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, vpc

I have a `lambda function` that sends the following request to get the IDs of all instances inside the region:

```
ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', os.environ['region'])
response = ec2_client.describe_instances(Filters=[{'Name':'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['pending', 'running','shutting-down','stopping','stopped'],}])
```

The lambda sends also a get request to an API REST installed inside a VPC and this API is not open to the internet:

```
resp = requests.get(os.environ['apidsi']+'/persons/emails')
```

I put my Lambda function inside a VPC so that I can query the API, but when I do that, the lambda times out and it does not access the EC2 instances inside other VPCs. The IAM role has all the necessary permissions :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecs:*",
                "ec2:*",
                "s3:*",
                "autoscaling:*",
                "cloudwatch:*",
                "dynamodb:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Security group is ok also I guess. So to sum up:

- When I put the lambda function inside a VPC: I can access the `API REST` but not the VPC resources, the lambda times out
- When I don't put the lambda function inside a VPC, the function gets all information about the VPC resources but can't access the API REST: also times out.

How to solve this problem ??
**For information: I assigned a public subnet to my Lambda function. This public subnet has an `Internet Gateway` attached, and it is in the same VPC as the instance hosting the API REST.**

Comment: So you want to access resources of one VPC from another, correct?

Comment: @TenorFlyy exactly

Comment: This isn't as straightforward as it may sound though. The two easier solutions are to either us VPC Peering or AWS Direct Connect as listed here https://aws.amazon.com/answers/networking/aws-single-region-multi-vpc-connectivity/ , but I strongly recommend you take the VPC Peering as partially meshed network.

Comment: I have 4 VPCs and I want to get information about all instances in all VPCs, so do I need to establish VPC peering with all of these VPCs ? This sounds really anti pattern to do only for a lambda function ..

Comment: Well, you can either expose your information via API GW or any other tools needed for the job or use the same VPC(this is a real anti pattern here). But either way, it will require some work.

Comment: Maybe this can help you out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html as well

Comment: @TenorFlyy thank you but aws lambda is not within the supported services to use VPC endpoints

Comment: My idea was that you can expose your services in secure way with it or at least part of them

Comment: @TenorFlyy could not figure out how to do that. I'm still stuck with this